# how do you iterate over a multiple pickled dictionaries

Tags: python, pickle

How do you pickle a dictionary, then write that and other pickled dictionaries to a file. Then open that file and iterate over the pickled dictionaries.

```py
import pickle
with open('board.json', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump({'x':'1', 'func': str}, f)
    pickle.dump({'x':'2', 'func': open}, f)

with open('board.json', 'rb') as f:
    for p in pickle.load(f):
        print(p)
```

Output:

```
x

func
```

Expected Output:

```
{'x':'1', 'func': str}

{'x':'2', 'func': open}
```

Comment: I am not sure you can write 2 dictionaries this way. Might be better to create a tuple of these dictionaries and then pickle them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option like @Suraaj had said is to create a tuple of these dictionaries as so.

```
import pickle
with open('board.json', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(({'x':'1', 'func': str},{'x':'2', 'func': open}), f)
```

This way when you iterate through your file

```
with open('board.json', 'rb') as f:
    for p in pickle.load(f):
        print(p)
```

you get

```
{'x': '1', 'func': <class 'str'>}
{'x': '2', 'func': <built-in function open>}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle

with open('board.json', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump({'x':'1', 'func': str}, f)
    pickle.dump({'x':'2', 'func': open}, f)

with open('board.json', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            print(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
```